Transpose select values with pandas dataframe?
I have a dataframe that goes as follows:
ID  Name    Item 1  Item 2  Item 3
DF093   Tony    wag dig set
DF890   Steven  wig sit sat
DF409   Maria   lag let can

I need create and retain two output files from it: First I need to create a new row for each item, with the corresponding 'Name' and 'ID', so it looks like:
Output#1
ID  Name        Items
DF093   Tony        wag     
DF093   Tony        dig
DF093   Tony        set
DF890   Steven      wig
DF890   Steven      sit
DF890   Steven      sat
DF409   Maria       lag
DF409   Maria       let
DF409   Maria       can 

Then I need to merge/group all items into one field, 'Items', like so:
Output #2
Output #2
ID  Name        Items
DF093   Tony        wag | dig | set 
DF890   Steven      wig | sit | sat
DF409   Maria       lag | let | can


I tried to use the transpose function, but that is not correct. I believe some sort of group by statement with an if conditional aggregation might work? Unsure of how to write it.
